# Weight Initialization Tensorflow tf.estimator

Tags: tensorflow, initialization

Is there a way to adjust the weight initialization in the pre-built tf.estimator?
I would like to use the method after Xavier (`tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer`) or from He. Which method is used by default? I couldn't figure it out from the documentation.

I use the DNNRegressor.

Answer (score 2):

`DNNRegressor` uses [glorot_uniform_initializer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/glorot_uniform_initializer) (aka Xavier uniform), it is hardcoded in the [implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4dcfddc5d12018a5a0fdca652b9221ed95e9eb23/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py#L102).

To use a different initializer with estimators API you have to use [custom estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/custom_estimators).

Comment: even before starting the training using ` tf.estimator.LinearRegressor`, we need to initialize the weights for our defined model, which API in tensorflow does that? Could you point me to it? It could be the case that tf is doing by itself(hardcoded), but how and from where?.

Comment: @anu, initializers API is here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/initializers, but estimators use it indirectly via [MonitoredSession](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/MonitoredSession) / [MonitoredTrainingSession](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/MonitoredTrainingSession).

Comment: thanks, but how one will get to know that which estimator in the `
Module: tf.estimator` is using which initializer indirectly. I mean there isn't any write-up in the documentation anywhere(I couldn't find it actually.) Eg. `tf.estimator.LinearRegressor` doesn't highlight which method it's using to initialise the weight! Is there a way to find it or print it. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Custom estimators require you to define your graph from scratch, you can pass  initializer for every layer/ operation(if its constructor takes initializer argument), it's done usually inside model_fn, or inside the function that defines the graph